Compactly supported wave packet in Schrödinger's evolution
Does the following result hold:
For any compactly supported wave packet, under free Schrödinger's evolution, it is no longer compactly supported after any finite time?

$\widehat{u_t}(\xi) =\widehat{u_0}(\xi) e^{-it|\xi|^2}$, and now the Paley-Wiener theorem shows that this is not the FT of a compactly supported ($L^2$) function since it is not of exponential type.

Yes, this follows from the representation of the solution of $i\partial_t u+ \Delta u=0, u(x,0)=u_0\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ as
$$u(x,t)=(2i t)^{-d/2} e^{ix^2/4t} \widehat{e^{i\cdot^2/4t} u_0(\cdot)}(x/2t)$$
where $\hat{f}(\xi)=(2\pi)^{-d/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{-ix\cdot \xi}f(x)\,dx$ is the Fourier transform of $f$, and the well-known fact that the Fourier transform of a non-zero, compactly supported function is no longer so.
